# SSRS Chart in Table, x-axis only at the bottom of the table

Tags: reporting-services

I'm creating a report using Visual Studio 2015.
I have a table containing a bar chart in each row.

This is what I have:

[image]

And I want to have a x-axis at the bottom of the table but only there and not in each row that relates to all graphs.

Something like this:

[image]
Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Those two pictures look identical to me. Not sure what you mean by "a x-axis at the bottom" I think your question need some editing to add more information or at least clarify what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this in the past. You can place an additional Chart in the footer of the table with the same width as your bar charts. You may have to wrestle with the padding. Turn off everything but the x-axis in the footer's bar chart and wrestle with the alignment by finding obscure offset properties and it should work.